# Spring Batch/Integration Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am having an issue with the inbound channel adapter and the whole application failing if the local directory does not exist, although I have auto-create-local-directory set to true.  It seems to be failing in the very beginning when creating the bean.  What can I do to make it either create the directory or at least not fail?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should share config and StackTrace as well.

Having `auto-create-local-directory="true"` and `directory does not exist` can tell me that your OS user doesn't have permission to create that directory. Just because `FileReadingMessageSource`:

```
protected void onInit() {
    Assert.notNull(directory, "'directory' must not be null");
    if (!this.directory.exists() && this.autoCreateDirectory) {
        this.directory.mkdirs();
    }
    Assert.isTrue(this.directory.exists(),
            "Source directory [" + directory + "] does not exist.");
```

> in the very beginning when creating the bean.